# 「ぬれているようにまっくらです」は一般的なたとえですか？

Tags: meaning, translation, interpretation

## Japanese

日本の小説を外国語に翻訳している外国人です。

今手がけている小説に、

> 二人は森の中にそろそろと入っていきました。空に残った明かりが少しは木の間からさしていると思ったのに、森の中に入ったとたんだれかが戸でも閉めてしまったように急に暗くなりました。冷たい空気が流れてきて、まわりは**ぬれているようにまっくらです**。

という一節があります。

最後の「ぬれているようにまっくらです」がわかりません。
「目を閉じているように真っ暗」「月が隠されているように真っ暗」ならすぐわかります・・・。
「濡れている」と「真っ暗」は全く関係がないように思いますが、これをみなさんはどういうふうに解釈されるでしょうか。

ちなみに、原稿ではこの最後の文はこのまま全てひらがなで表記されています。

## English

I translate Japanese novels and I found the following passage in the one I am working on at the moment:

> 二人は森の中にそろそろと入っていきました。空に残った明かりが少しは木の間からさしていると思ったのに、森の中に入ったとたんだれかが戸でも閉めてしまったように急に暗くなりました。冷たい空気が流れてきて、まわりは**ぬれているようにまっくらです**。

I have a difficult time understanding the last phrase, 「ぬれているようにまっくらです」. Phrases like「目を閉じているように真っ暗」 and 「月が隠されているように真っ暗」 make sense to me, but 「濡れている」 and 「真っ暗」 just don't feel like they're related. I would like to know how you would translate this phrase.

By the way, the phrase is written completely in Hiragana in the original novel as well.

Comment: I would suggest adding an English version of the question. You can do so by editing this question (instead of submitting another question.) The idea is to make it more accessible to people in all levels of Japanese proficiency. See discussion at https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22/do-questions-have-to-be-in-english .

Comment: FWIW ぬれ and まみれ share the same kanji. If ぬれ was wrongly converted from まみれ, then it kinda makes sense to be "covered" in darkness. But it's probably a wrong hypothesis.

Answer (score 5):

## Japanese

一般的でない表現だと思います。可能なら、著者に正確な意図を質問したほうがいいのではないでしょうか。

「濡れ羽色」はつやのある黒色のことですが、これにヒントを得た表現なのかもしれません。

## English

I don't think it's a common expression. You might want to ask the author to clarify their intent, if possible.

This reminded me of another expression 濡れ羽色 (which is part of the standard vocabulary) that refers to a particular kind of glossy blackness. The author might have taken an inspiration from that.

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！「濡れ羽色」、調べてみます！

ちなみに、「ぬれる」と入力すると「塗れる」に変換できるので、「（黒く）塗られたように真っ暗」かと一瞬思っていましたが、可能形の「塗れる」もちょっとおかしいですね。塗られたように真っ暗、ならちょっと納得しますが・・・。

Comment: @Metch 濡れ羽色だけだとわかりづらいかもしれませんが、一般には[カラス](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%83%8F%E3%81%AE%E6%BF%A1%E3%82%8C%E7%BE%BD%E8%89%B2-467457)が念頭に置かれます.